# Edit already-existing ASP.NET web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, dll, vs-web-application-project

Btw, I am quite new to C#, ASP.net, Visual Studio, etc.:

I FTPed into a remote server to get the code for an already-existing, functioning web application. I ran it on a local server quite easily; however, I'm struggling to rebuild the project in VS Express and see changes I make in the C# (an aspx.cs file) code. I build the .csproj file (with and without the changes I make), but I get the following error for BAL, DAL, and BO:

Error   11  The type or namespace name 'DAL' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

They also generate warnings:

Warning 385 The referenced component 'BAL' could not be found.

BAL.dll, DAL.dll, and BO.dll all exist in the bin folder. When running VS Express, they are in the folder tree under References but have warning signs next to them.

How do I go about testing changes I make to the C# files? Is there an easier way to edit the backend of an already-running .NET app? Should I decompile the project_name.dll, alter it, and recompile it?

Comment: You would need to re-build those references by creating it like if they were new... I unfortunately don't have a VS at hand right now to give a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Warning signs next to the reference means it can't be found, hence the "missing namespace" error.
Are the DAL, BAL and BO projects in the same solution?

You can try to simply remove the references and add them again with the correct location. I guess there are some path-changes in there...

Answer (score 0):

First you need to delete them from the references and then rereference them.  I would copy them from the Bin folder to somewhere else and reference them from there.  That will allow Visual Studio copy them itself.

If you don't have the source code you could find it rather tricky.  Have you got the *.cs files that match the project?  If not you will find it very difficult to ammend the project indeed.

Comment: There are many .cs files. BAL, DAL and BO only exist in the bin folder with the extensions .llb and .pdb (which I assume is fine).

Comment: Is there a *.sln file there at all?  You may be luck and have all the source code you need to amend the project.  However without the source code for the BO and DAL it maybe tricky.  Can't someone give you the original project.  It would be much easier.  Also take a look at the Microsoft Community Edition of Visual Studio.  It is a little more substantial than the old Express version of VS.

Comment: No sln file. I'll ask for the original project. Thanks! If I get the sln, will the source for the BO and DAL be necessary?